# Python mailer: Cannot import name Mailer error

Tags: python, email

I am using this Python script to test sending emails programmatically:

```
from mailer import Mailer
from mailer import Message

message = Message(From="myname@gmail.com",
              To="myname@aol.com",
              charset="utf-8")
 message.Subject = "An HTML Email"
message.Html = """This email uses <strong>HTML</strong>!"""
message.Body = """This is alternate text."""

sender = Mailer('smtp.gmail.com')
sender.send(message)
```

I believe I have installed Mailer-0.7 (but how do I check?), and am running Python 2.7 on this iMac.  Trouble is I am getting this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "email.py", line 1, in <module>
from mailer import Mailer
File "/Users/jeremycondie/Desktop/mailer.py", line 31, in <module>
import smtplib
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 46, in <module>
import email.utils
File "/Users/jeremycondie/Desktop/email.py", line 1, in <module>
from mailer import Mailer
ImportError: cannot import name Mailer
```

Answer (score 3):

The `from mailer import X` statement is importing from `/Users/jeremycondie/Desktop/mailer.py`, try renaming that file.

**Edit:** To get Mailer's version (after fixing the filename):

```
import mailer
print mailer.__version__
```

**Edit 2:**
If in the future you run into a similar situation, first check the module location and its attributes to discard that a local file is shadowing a module:

```
print mailer.__file__
print dir(mailer)
```